# subdirectory path opening root website why

Tags: ee2, .htaccess

there are two site on my server 1 on root and other one in a sub folder named /A

when i am inputting my sub folder's url its opening root website

there is no .htaccess file present .

root website is working correct.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about server settings, not really related to EE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.htaccess is not only one place where rules can be located.  First of all needs to understand what do you use on your site as webserver.

For example it can be Apache, Apache+NGINX, NGIX+php-fpm. The last one don't use .htaccess . All rules is  nginx config files.

Apache can also keep rules in his config. .htaccess is only way to override default config (in case if apache config allow it *AllowOverride All*).